# Path of the current InkScape file from python script

Tags: python, inkscape

Is there any way to get the name and path of the current document opened in inkScape from a python script?

The script is called via the inkscape extensions menu (via an inx file).

Comment: Are you writing an external python script, or is it called as an extension via `inx` file?

Comment: @SanjayManohar What about to answer both, or only for the one You know? I'm interested as well, inx in my case.

Comment: This is possible with Inkscape 1.1 (to be released this spring)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same question in 2022, so, timely answer:

Inkscape extensions work with temporary files. The path to temp file is passed to extension as the last argument, so `sys.argv[-1]` gets that temporary path. It is also available as `self.options.input_file`.

If you need the original .svg, not the temp file:
The name of the current file is available as `self.svg.name`. (docs: inkex.base.InkscapeExtension.[name](https://inkscape-extensions-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/inkex-modules.html#inkex.base.InkscapeExtension.name))

The path to it is available as `self.svg_path()`. (docs: inkex.base.InkscapeExtension.[svg_path()](https://inkscape-extensions-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/inkex-modules.html#inkex.base.InkscapeExtension.svg_path))

**So, the full path to current loaded SVG is** `os.path.join(self.svg_path(), self.svg.name)`